# Adding jQuery snippet to Drupal website

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to add the following snippet to my Drupal 7 website but I'm not sure where to put it. I really only want it on one particular blog post but if it's easier to apply to the entire website that would also be fine.

```
$(function() {
 $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
   if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
     var target = $(this.hash);
     target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
     if (target.length) {
       $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: target.offset().top
       }, 1000);
       return false;
     }
   }
 });
});
```

[Screenshot of website file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUSXK.jpg)

I thought I could just pop it into the common.js file but when I do so, nothing changes. Here's the code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Remove scrollbar placed for non flicking carousel/no js version, show the thumbnails
    $("#carousels").css("height","auto").css("overflow","visible");
    $("#carousels .thumbs").css("display","block");

$(function() {
 $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
   if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
     var target = $(this.hash);
     target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
     if (target.length) {
       $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: target.offset().top
       }, 1000);
       return false;
     }
   }
 });
});
)};
```

Any ideas on how I can get this functionality added?

Comment: `$(function() {}); function is eqaul to `$(document).ready(function(){});`, so you don;t need to create another function wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @ShaileshRathod I removed the `$(function() {});` but this snippet is still not functional. Any other ideas?

Comment: do you have fiddle link? so I can help you in this.

Comment: Flush all cache (drush cc all )

Comment: @ShaileshRathod I'm not sure how to add this to js fiddle because it's on a very large website relying on many different files...? I tested the actual code itself in Code Pen and it worked fine. It just seems to be the placement that I have wrong.

Comment: I suggest writing a simple jquery function to test your code is actually making it's way through to the front end. I'm not sure what common.js is but all the files in your screenshot probably run through a compiler like gulp. A way to check this is to navigate to common.js in your browser and see it your changes are there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the JS file to as specific page with the following code. So imagine the page you want to add the code to is `www.yourwebsite.com/node/9`

```
  function yourmodule_page_alter(&$page) {
    $pathElements = explode('/', current_path());

    if (count($pathElements) == 2 && $pathElements[0] == 'node' && $pathElements[1] == '9') {
      global $base_url;
      $path = $base_url . '/' . drupal_get_path('module','yourmodule');

      drupal_add_js(
        $path . "/includes/js/yourcustom.js",
        array(
          'type' => 'file',
          'scope' => 'header',
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

You can find more information about `hook_page_alter()` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7.x) and more info about `drupal_add_js()` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x).